# Yii2 после переноса на сервер проекта, не создает сессию после авторизации

Tags: php, yii2, авторизация

После переноса перестала происходить создании сессии пользователя. Однако авторизация происходит. 
Авторицию делаю так

```
if ($this->validate()) {
    $db = new User();
    foreach($db->find()->where(['username' => $this->username])->all() as $key=>$val)
    {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($val, $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
    }
    $db->username = $this->username;
    $db->password = sha1($this->password);
    $db->password_hash = sha1($this->password);
    $db->created_at = strtotime(time());
    $db->updated_at = strtotime(time());
    $db->email = $this->username;
    $db->status = 1;
    $db->auth_key = 1;
    $db->password_reset_token = sha1($this->password);
    $db->save();
    return Yii::$app->user->login($db, $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
}
```

При переборе фореча получаю объект пользователя из бд. 
Далее

```
return Yii::$app->user->login($val, $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
```

Тут то и происходит магия - авторизация происходит но при выводе var_dump(Yii::$app->user);
Выдает объект без нужных параметров, видимо что с записью сессий... Помогите разобраться, доступ к серверу есть. Нужно понять почему не записывает сессии.

Answer (score 2):

Ну если код не менялся, то думаю причину нужно искать в конфигурации сервера. Попробуйте проверить на обеих серверах. Плюс не помешал бы **config** с параметрами **session**, **request** и **user**

```
$params = [
    'session.auto_start',
    'session.name',
    'session.save_path',
    'session.gc_maxlifetime',
    'session.cookie_lifetime',
    'session.cookie_lifetime',
    'session.cookie_path',
    'session.cookie_domain',
    'session.cookie_secure',
    'session.cookie_httponly',
    'session.use_cookies',
    'session.use_only_cookies',
];

$tmp = [];

foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
    $tmp[$value] = ini_get($value);
}

print_r($tmp);
```

Comment: Array ( [session.auto_start] => 0 [session.name] => PHPSESSID [session.save_path] => /var/lib/php/session [session.gc_maxlifetime] => 1440 [session.cookie_lifetime] => 0 [session.cookie_path] => / [session.cookie_domain] => [session.cookie_secure] => [session.cookie_httponly] => [session.use_cookies] => 1 [session.use_only_cookies] => 1 )

Comment: А на втором? Различия есть?